# Is there a rigorous proof that photons do not acquire mass through renormalization?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, photons, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization

The standard proof that photons don't become massive in 4d QED is calculating the photon propagator and checking that it has a pole at momentum $q^2=0$.

The propagator is obtained summing loop diagrams of the type:

[image]

[image]

But this does not consider more complicated diagrams like:

[image]

Is there a way to include all possible diagrams?
Can the proof be extended to include the rest of the EW sector and QCD?

Ward identity is often mentioned as a proof of massless photons, but it seems that it only indicates transverse photons.

Comment: Based on the fact that the PDG book includes photon mass searches, I wold expect the answer is no. But that's just a guess.

Comment: The search for photon mass is for the eventuality of the QED model being wrong.

Comment: "*But this does not consider more complicated diagrams like:*" Yes it does. The pole at $p^2=0$ corresponds to the one-particle irreducible function, which includes your "more complicated diagram" as well. In fact, and as the name indicates, the one-particle irreducible function includes *all* one-particle irreducible diagrams. In the general case (non-abelian gauge theories), you need Slavnov-Taylor instead of Ward, but the philosophy is the same

Comment: There is an equivalence between being massless and being a gauge field with unbroken gauge symmetry. So the Ward identity *is* proof that the photon remains massless - the photon acquiring mass is equivalent to the gauge symmetry being broken is equivalent to the Ward identity being violated. Is that an acceptable answer or do you really want to do diagrammatics here?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I've heard that statement, but how is that compatible with 2d being massive yet gauge invariance is preserved?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform A better way to rephrase the question is that many notes just sum simple loop diagrams, instead of all 1PI diagrams. I was asking how to do the correct calculation, but I guess people simply use the Ward identity.  I'm curious why they get a sensible result, since eliminating diagrams would break gauge invariance.

Comment: I don't know what specifically you mean, but in general, two dimensions are very special and most of the standard statements about QFT should be thought of in three dimensions or higher unless stated otherwise.

Comment: @jinawee I don't think "that many notes just sum simple loop diagrams, instead of all 1PI diagrams." Every book/lectures I've read considers 1PI diagrams. Where have you seen someone eliminate diagrams? [doing so would definitely break gauge-invariance, and the photon would appear to be massive]

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/677454/226902 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/640130/226902 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/342994/226902

Answer (score 8):

There is a prove in the lecture notes 12 of [Relativistic Quantum Field Theory II](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-324-relativistic-quantum-field-theory-ii-fall-2010/lecture-notes/MIT8_324F10_Lecture12.pdf) from MIT OCW based on functional method. I will outline the prove here.
The exact propagator of photon is
$$\mathcal{G}(x)_{\mu\nu} = \langle  \Omega | T A_{\mu}(x)A_{\nu}(0)| \Omega \rangle_C.$$
It can be represented by the following diagram
[image]
Let us define $i\Pi^{\mu\nu}$ to be the sum of all 1-particle-irreducible insertions into the photon propagator. So, we have
$$\mathcal{G}(k) = G_{\rm F}(k) + G_{\rm F}(k)(i\Pi(k))G_{\rm F}(k) + \cdots = G_{\rm F}(k) \frac{1}{1-i\Pi(k)G_{\rm F}(k)}.$$
$G_{\rm F}(p)_{\mu\nu}$ is the free propagator of photon and so we have
$$iG_{\rm F}(p)_{\mu\nu}  = \frac{\eta_{\mu\nu}}{k^2-i\epsilon} - (1-\xi)\frac{k_{\mu}k_{\nu}}{(k^2-i\epsilon)^2} = \frac{1}{k^2-i\epsilon}(P^T_{\mu\nu} + \xi P^L_{\mu\nu}),$$
where 
$$P^T_{\mu\nu} \equiv \eta_{\mu\nu} - \frac{k_{\mu}k_{\nu}}{k^2}, \quad  P^L_{\mu\nu} \equiv \frac{k_{\mu}k_{\nu}}{k^2}.$$
($\xi = 1$ is the so-called Feynman gauge)

It is easy to derive that
$$(iG_{\rm F})^{-1}_{\mu\nu} = k^2 (P^T_{\mu\nu} + \frac{1}{\xi} P^L_{\mu\nu}).$$
We may also decompose $i\Pi^{\mu\nu}$ as
$$\Pi^{\mu\nu} = P_T^{\mu\nu}f_T(k^2) +  P_L^{\mu\nu}f_L(k^2) = \eta^{\mu\nu}f_T + \frac{k^{\mu}k^{\nu}}{k^2}(f_L-f_T)$$
Therefore,
$$(i\mathcal{G})^{-1}_{\mu\nu} = (k^2-f_T(k^2))P^T_{\mu\nu} + (\frac{k^2}{\xi}-f_L(k^2)) P^L_{\mu\nu},$$
$$\mathcal{G}(k)_{\mu\nu} = \frac{-i}{k^2-f_T(k^2)}P^T_{\mu\nu} + \frac{-i}{\frac{k^2}{\xi}-f_L(k^2)} P^L_{\mu\nu}.$$
If $f_{T,L}(k^2 = 0) \neq 0$, a mass will be generated for the photon. Because $\Pi(k)$ comes from 1PI diagrams, it should not be singular at $k^2 =0 $, and so $f_L - f_T = O(k^2)$, as $k \to 0$.

---

We define the generating functional $E[J,\eta,\overline{\eta}]$ for connected diagrams in QED by
$$Z[J,\eta,\overline{\eta}] = e^{-iE[J,\eta,\overline{\eta}]}$$
So,
$$\mathcal{G}(x-y)_{\mu\nu} = i  \frac{\delta^2 E[J,\eta,\overline{\eta}]}{\delta J^{\mu}(x) \delta J^{\nu}(y)}\bigg|_{J,\eta,\overline{\eta}=0}$$
For infinitesimal gauge transformations, we have $\delta A_{\mu} = \partial_{\mu} \lambda $, $\delta \Psi = ie_0\lambda\Psi$ and $\delta \overline{\Psi}  = -ie_0 \lambda \overline{\Psi}$. 
Under a change of variables in the path integral, $Z[J,\eta,\overline{\eta}]$ will remain the same. 
Recall that
$$Z[J,\eta,\overline{\eta}] = \int \mathcal{D}A \mathcal{D}\overline{\Psi} \mathcal{D}\Psi e^{i\int d^4x [\mathcal{L} + JA + \overline{\eta}\Psi + \overline{\Psi}\eta]} $$
where 
$$\mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu} + \overline{\Psi} (i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}-m_0) \Psi + e_0j^{\mu} A_{\mu} - \frac{1}{2\xi}(\partial_{\mu}A^{\mu})^2$$

The change of action is
$$\delta S = -\frac{1}{\xi} \int d^4x \partial_{\mu} A^{\mu} \partial^2 \lambda + \int d^4x J^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\lambda + ie_0\overline{\eta}\Psi\lambda - ie_0\overline{\Psi}\eta\lambda$$

Hence, we must have
$$\int d^4x \lambda(x) \int \mathcal{D}A \mathcal{D}\overline{\Psi} \mathcal{D}\Psi e^{iS} \left[ -\frac{1}{\xi} \partial^2 \partial_{\mu} A^{\mu} - \partial_{\mu}J^{\mu}  + ie_0(\overline{\eta}\Psi - \overline{\Psi}\eta)\right] = 0 $$
Since
$$\langle A_{\mu}(x) \rangle_{J,\eta,\overline{\eta}} = - \frac{\delta E}{\delta J^{\mu}} \quad \langle \Psi(x) \rangle_{J,\eta,\overline{\eta}} = - \frac{\delta E}{\delta \overline{\eta}} \quad \langle \overline{\Psi}(x) \rangle_{J,\eta,\overline{\eta}} =  \frac{\delta E}{\delta \eta}$$
The above equation can be written as
$$\frac{1}{\xi} \partial^2 \partial^{\mu}\frac{\delta E}{\delta J^{\mu}} - \partial_{\mu}J^{\mu} - ie_0\left[ \overline{\eta}\frac{\delta E}{\delta \overline{\eta}} + \frac{\delta E}{\delta \eta} \eta \right]=0$$
By differentiation with $\delta J$ at $J,\eta,\overline{\eta} = 0$, we can get
$$\frac{1}{\xi} \partial^2 \partial^{\mu} \frac{\delta^2 E[J,\eta,\overline{\eta}]}{\delta J^{\mu}(x) \delta J^{\nu}(y)}\bigg|_{J,\eta,\overline{\eta}=0} - \partial_{\nu} \delta(x-y) = 0$$
that is,
$$\frac{i}{\xi}\partial^2 \partial^{\mu} \mathcal{G}(x-y)_{\mu\nu}+ \partial_{\nu} \delta(x-y) = 0 $$
or, written in momentum-space,
$$-\frac{i}{\xi}k^2 k^{\mu} \mathcal{G}(k)_{\mu\nu}+ k_{\nu} = 0$$
So
$$- \frac{k^2}{k^2-\xi f_L(k^2)} k_{\nu} + k_{\nu} = 0$$
Which means $f_L(k^2) =0$ and so, we have $f_T(k^2) \to O(k^2)$ as $k^2 \to 0$. The exact propagator of photon is
$$\mathcal{G}(k)_{\mu\nu} = \frac{-i}{k^2(1-\pi(k^2))}P^T_{\mu\nu} + \frac{-i\xi}{k^2} P^L_{\mu\nu}$$
where $\pi(k^2) \equiv \frac{f_T(k^2)}{k^2}$.
The exact propagator has a pole at $k^2=0$, so photon remain massless after quantum correction.

The discussion concerning on QCD corrections is beyond my knowledge and I am looking forward to a better answer.